# wp_query returns only first from variable array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, variables

I need to have variable containing array to put inside post__in => array ($variable), but with the posted code wp_query returns only one (the first post id number).

I tried to hardcode 'post__in' => array(24,23,25) and the query displays all three posts but I can't figure out how to make it dynamic (to have post__in => array ($variable)). I suspect there's something with the '' but can't find out.

```
$selected_ids = '24,23,25';   //needs to be equal to $_POST['selected_ids'];


 $args2 = array(
'post_type' => 'specs', 
'post__in' => array($selected_ids)
);

$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );


if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {

while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    $query2->the_post();
    echo '<li class="col-lg-3">
<div class="col compare-item-field">
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button></br>
<p>' . get_the_title( $query2->post->ID ) . '</p> 
<p class="text-muted">at ' . get_field( 'myField', $query2->post->ID ) . '</p>
</div>
</li>';
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `'post__in' => array($selected_ids)` is using an array that's got one item in it that's an "ID" of "24,23,25".

That's because `$selected_ids = '24,23,25';` is a *string*. If you're getting `'24,23,25'` from an input value, you can use PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to turn that string into an array, by exploding it at the commas.

```
$ids = '24,23,25';
$selected_ids = explode( ',', $ids );
```

That will return an actual array:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> string(2) "24"
    [1]=> string(2) "23"
    [2]=> string(2) "25"
}
```